# Airflow CLI: How to get status of dag tasks in Airflow 1.10.12?

Tags: airflow, aws-cli, airflow-2.x

In Airflow 2.0, you can get the status of tasks in a dag by running CLI command: `airflow tasks states-for-dag-run`. (See docs here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#state_repeat1)

What's the equivalent in Airflow 1.10.12? I can't seem to find it in [the 1.10.12 docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/cli-ref.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent as this is a new CLI command of Airflow 2.0.

In Airflow 1.10.12 you can do ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/cli-ref.html)):

```
airflow task_state [-h] [-sd SUBDIR] dag_id task_id execution_date
```